# error "can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar" when I try to get the index of a row of a pandas dataframe as an integer

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with stock symbols and many other columns. I have a simplified version of the excel file below:

|  | Symbol | Industry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAPL | Technology Manufacturing |
| 1 | MSFT | Technology Manufacturing |
| 2 | TSLA | Electric Car Manufacturing |

Essentially, I am trying to get the Industry based on the Symbol.
For example, if I use 'AAPL' I want to get 'Technology Manufacturing'. Here is my code so far.

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file1 = 'file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file1)
stock = 'AAPL'
row_index = df[df['Symbol'] == stock].index.item()
industry = df['Industry'][row_index]
print(industry)
```

after trying to get row_index, I get an error: "ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar"

can someone solve this? Also let's say row_index works: is this code (below) correct?

```
industry = df['Industry'][row_index]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
stock = 'AAPL'
industry = df[df['Symbol'] == stock]['Industry'][0]
```

**OR:**, if you want to search using `index`, use `df.loc`:

```
stock = 'AAPL'
industry = df.loc[df[df['Symbol'] == stock].index, 'Industry'][0]
```

But the first one's much better.